# How to get last date value

Tags: date, tableau-api, calculated-field

I have a problem to determine last value date from my data.

Here's the example of my data

[image]

And this is the formula for "Last Date Show" calculated field:

if [Date] = {FIXED [Panelistid]:MAX([Date])} THEN 'SHOW'
ELSE NULL
END

According to the result that i shared on the top, Panelists 244196 should have "SHOW" value on the 2nd EventID, also Panelists 253487 should have "SHOW" value in 4th EventID, what even strange is Panelists 254595 is not showing "SHOW" value while it's only have 1 value.

I wonder what's wrong with the formula.

Edited:

I found the problem. Its come from my data. Something like this

[image]

The way I do it was exclude the record that have NULL value first, and then apply the "Last Date Show" variable. I think that's why it didn't show 'SHOW' value, because it was filtered first and then calculate.

The problem is, how can I do the "Last Date Show" across the data that only have value (not NULL value)

Thanks

Randy

Comment: quite strange... just to check everything possible, have you already tried to create a calculated field with just the fixed max date ({FIXED [Panelistid]:MAX([Date])}) and add it to the row shelf? what does it show?
I've tried your formula with the superstore dataset and all works fine

Comment: hi Fabio thanks for your reply. I have found the problem, the detail is in my first post. Thanks

Comment: very well, maybe try to update/answer in order to mate this post usefull. happy to help in case :-)

Comment: Hi Fabio, actually i haven't solved the problem yet. The updated problem is on the first post. Thanks

Comment: Assuming that your input is the one you've posted in your edit, could you please add the desired output? I mean, you want only rows regarding EventID E1, E2 (show), E4 and E5 (show)?

Comment: I've posted a possible solution in the following answer. Please let me know if it solved your problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you want just 4 of your 6 input rows (excluding the ones with value = null), this could be you solution:

[image]

As you can see, the only thing you may have forgotten is to use a CONTEXT FILTER (right click on your filter and click "add to context") since they are **resolved before FIXED operator**.

Take a look at this schema to better understand how Tableau works in terms of "time":

[image]

Hope it helps.

EDIT:
take a look at the official documentation: http://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/pro/online/windows/en-us/filtering_context.html

FF

Comment: in order to better understand context filter, i updated my asnwer with an external link to Tableau documentation. don't hesitate to ask for more help